Suppose $\cos^5\theta-\sin^5\theta\lt7(\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta), \theta\in[0,2π)$. Then find the range of $\theta$

Suppose $\cos^5\theta-\sin^5\theta\lt7(\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta), \theta\in[0,2π)$. Then find the range of $\theta$

My Attempt:
$$\cos^3\theta(\cos^2\theta+7)<\sin^3\theta(7+\sin^2\theta)$$
Case I: $\theta$ is in 1st or 4th quadrant, so,
$$\cos^2\theta+7<\tan^3\theta(7+\sin^2\theta)$$
Since LHS is positive, so, $\theta$ must be in first quadrant. Does that also mean $\tan\theta$ should be greater than $1$?
Case II: 2nd, 3rd quadrant.
$$\cos^2\theta+7>\tan^3\theta(7+\sin^2\theta)$$
Does that mean 2nd quadrant is acceptable and in 3rd quadrant, $\tan\theta<1?$
Should the final answer be $(\fracπ4, \frac{5π}4)$?


Your answer is correct, and there is an easier way to go about it.

From your first step of $\cos^3\theta(\cos^2\theta+7)<\sin^3\theta(7+\sin^2\theta)$ observe this can be expressed as $\sin^3(\theta + \pi/2)(\sin^2(\theta + \pi/2)+7)<\sin^3\theta(7+\sin^2\theta)$. And so it is that both sides of the inequality are the same function with a phase shift of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. They have the same period, maximum and minimum  values.
Furthermore, the equality holds when $\sin{x} = \sin{(x + \pi/2)}$, or indeed when $x = \pi/4 , 5\pi/4$.
Now, it follows that $\cos^3\theta(\cos^2\theta+7)<\sin^3\theta(7+\sin^2\theta)$ when $\cos{x} < \sin{x}$ as signs keeps their integrity on odd powers.
Hence, $\cos{x} < \sin{x}$ when $x \in (\pi/4 , 5\pi/4)$.

I didn’t understand what you meant by ‘integrity of odd powers’?

@MathGuy Since the powers are either $3$ or $5$, both will stay negative when powered. So we need not to consider any absolute values that may affect the solution.
